# Adding new node to Cassandra cluster when initial_token is already specified

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a three node Cassandra cluster. Every node has initial_token configuration parameter holding 256 tokens.

Now I have to add a fourth node and the question is how to calculate initial_token parameter for it (strategy/algorithm/tool)?

Is it possible to move 256/4=64 tokens from every existing node to the new node? What will happen if:

1. I will take 64 tokens from initial_token on every node and set them on the new node;
2. remove those tokens from configs on original nodes;
3. restart the cluster; (I think every original node will still hold rows for moved tokens)
4. run "nodetool move" for every migrated token

Answer (score 4):

you manually set the node token's or C* calculate them and assigned?

if C* take them to Nodes, you didn't worry for assign tokens, before a new node start to joining to cluster, range than owned by new node calculated by other nodes an send to the new node and you are relaxed for this job!

another perspective you must consider is a using single token or vnode?
those are different from both.

Comment: I suspect C* calculated them before, and later they were set manually during dump recovery or because of something else.

Comment: when you run a cluster, do any job for assigning the tokens to nodes?

Comment: if actually, you don't try it and the cluster has a normal status, we find out the C* it self-calculate the tokens and assigned them to nodes.

after all, you have two approaches to tell C* assign the tokens. single token and vnode, try to google those!

Comment: Eventually, I found that initial_token parameter is used when C* starts the first time - so this means that I have vnodes enabled and new node could join the ring and I can relax with initial_token settings.